# unable to assign output of FOR loop into another variable in a batch file

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

I have used `FOR /F` to access the value in the file "last_bkp_date.txt" inside a batch file.

The result of `%%a` is okay, but i am unable to assign value to `v_abc`.

I have used `set v_abc =` before the `for` loop to especially delete / remove any past assignment done to this variable.

Can somebody help me on this?

```
@SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off

set v_abc =

FOR  /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%a IN (last_bkp_date.txt) DO (  
  set v_abc =%%a
  echo value of a: %%a
  echo value of abc: !v_abc!
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rookie mistake of adding a space after a variable name (`set v_abc =%%a`).

You can fix it by either

1. Changing `set v_abc =%%a` to `set v_abc=%%a`

   **Or**
2. Changing `echo Value of abc: !v_abc!` to `echo Value of abc: !v_abc !`.

Simple.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `SET variable=value`. Your problem is the space between the variable name and the `=` sign.

Just try this

```
set v_abc=%%a
```

and voilà!

The reason for this is that in Windows environment variable names can contain spaces. But it is not recommended, so as an alternative solution to your problem you could access the variable including the space, this way

```
echo value of abc: !v_abc !
```